# Nodejs cassandra datatype issue

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

i'm using node-cassandra-cql driver ( https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql ) to do sample select into a cassandra column family.

My cf has three column with that datatypes:

```
1 - value -> text
2 - date  -> timestamp
3 - hits  -> counter
```

Using nodeJS to fetch rows i do:

```
client.execute('SELECT date,value,hits FROM cf LIMIT 100', [],
      function(err, result) {
        if(err){
            var error = {error:true,message:err};
            res.send(error);
        }
        else{
            var trends = {};
            for(var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++){
                var row      = result.rows[i];
                console.log(row.date);
                console.log(row.hits);
            }
        }
        }
);
```

The console log gives me:

```
{
    "low": 1342763392,
    "high": 323,
    "unsigned": false
}
{
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0,
    "unsigned": false
}
```

What i need to do to get correct value?

Thanks!

Comment: instead of counter you can use "int" or "double" data-type and check whether it is working or not.
Because till i know for using counter data-type that field has to be primary key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra counter column value are a 64-bit signed integer (bigints), in the Node.js driver are represented as [Google Closure's Long](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_math_Long.html).

To get the string representation of the decimal value of the bigint, you can use #toString() method.

```
//"1", "2", ...
row.hits.toString();
```

Comment: That's the answer! Thanks!

Comment: How about parseInt()? It looks that it gives me correct values, but can I rely on it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer by jorgebg is also applicable when executing COUNT(*).

For example: 
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM my_table;

In that case to extract the value I used:
result.rows[0].count.toString();

Answer (score -1):

```
const str = result.first().count;
const count = JSON.parse(str);
```